# Open a link of search result in Google or YouTube using Python automatically

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am creating a speech assistant using speech_recognition in Python. So far I am able to get the search results in Google and YouTube, by giving input voice commands.

But How do I open the links of these search results?

For Example, please refer the picture below:

[image]

In the above screenshot shows the search results for: "open the first link form Google search results using Python". I would like to open the first link of stackoverflow.com automatically.

I would also like to do the same thing with YouTube search results.

Please guide me with the proper approach to accomplish this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. One suggestion is, All the html pages have the html tags. You can parse then using lxml in Python and extract <a href> for all the search result. All the urls will be in list and using the index you can open the page

Comment: Dear contributors - Please leave your comment when you downvote.  BTW - i did not downvoted your question

Comment: I would suggest not scraping Google.com and rather use an actual Python library that'll do that for you

Comment: @Backtrack Thank very much for the suggestion. Maybe I can try the same method you mentioned by  parsing the data with beautifulsoup.

Comment: @GauravPK- yup. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup!

1. Download the page using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
2. Parse the HTML using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
3. Look through the HTML for a way to identify the  tags with the page.find_all('a', href=True) function

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest method for this task:

1. Install google module, write in command prompt:

> pip install google

2. Write the following code there after in your python IDE:

> ```
> import googlesearch as gs   
> import webbrowser as wb   
> query=input("Enter what you want to search: ")   
> first_link=gs.search(query,num=1,tld="co.in",stop=1,pause=0)  
> for i in first_link:
>     wb.open_new_tab(i)
> ```

3. Just wait a few seconds and the first result will open in your default browser.
   (Tip: try writing "play song_name on youtube")
   Having any problem with this code? Feel free to comment it down.

Comment: Please check your answer again. 
pip install webbrowser generate the following error: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webbrowser (from versions: none)

Comment: @godidier webbrowser module comes inbuilt with python so doesn't require to be installed. Just run the given code by installing google only.

Comment: @godidier Upvote it and respond if it worked